# Images NOT working inside of Dropdown Country List with jQuery div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Trying to add images into the left of dropdown country list

I have created the country list and added the corresponding popup divs below it, but when trying to add the Images into the divs they're not working but the code is working as it should.

Here is the code so far and I really appreciate the time taken to read my code

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("select").change(function(){
        $(this).find("option:selected").each(function(){
            var optionValue = $(this).attr("value");
            if(optionValue){
                $(".box").not("." + optionValue).hide();
                $("." + optionValue).show();
            } else{
                $(".box").hide();
            }
        });
    }).change();
});
```

```css
<style>
    .box{
        color: #fff;
        padding: 20px;
        display: none;
        margin-top: 20px;
    }
    .UnitedKingdom{ background: #ff0000; }
    .UnitedStates{ background: #228B22; }
    .EuropeanCountries{ background: #bbb; }
    .Afganistan{ background: #aaa; }
    .Albania{ background: #eee; }
</style>
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>

    <div>
        <select>
            <option>Choose Your Region</option>
            <option value="UnitedKingdom" data-image="/icons/icon_calendar.gif">United Kingdom</option>
            <option value="UnitedStates">
            <img src="img_girl.jpg" alt="Girl in a jacket" width="500" height="600">
            United States</option>
            <option value="EuropeanCountries">European Countries</option>
            <option value="Afganistan">Afghanistan</option>
            <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    
    

    <div class="UnitedKingdom box"><h1>You have selected <strong>red option</strong> so i am here</div>
    <div class="UnitedStates box">You have selected <strong>green option</strong> so i am here</div>
    <div class="EuropeanCountries box">You have selected <strong>blue option</strong> so i am here</div>
    <div class="Afganistan box">You have selected <strong>green option</strong> so i am here</div>
    <div class="Albania box">You have selected <strong>blue option</strong> so i am here</div>
```

Comment: Images aren't allowed in `options`. If you have ever seen them, what you have seen is the select converted to HTML like a UL / LI or div etc on page load, where images are allowed.

Comment: Are you trying to add images to divs? Because no where in your code is that happening.

Comment: It would be good if i could display images only in the dropdown menu not in the actual body but if you say its not possible then okay - something like this is what I had in mind- https://prnt.sc/v38y13  and if it can be done without text that okay and just display an image instead of United Kingdom for exmaple.

Comment: That screenshot is referring to a plugin that converts the select to HTML elements. You can use that plugin to do it. Why don't you use that plugin? https://designwithpc.com/Plugins/ddSlick

Comment: I have tried but I wasn't sure if I could use my own images or weather I would be limited to using a library of images from ddSlick

Comment: my issue is not with using the plugin, it is combining both of them because the first one i posted changes every option you select

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the image tag in option tag.

If you want to display the image, try this library.

https://github.com/marghoobsuleman/ms-Dropdown